# Firebase showing error on onSnapshot if some value is coming from await

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am building an application in which I am classifying the the post and user by a roomid adding `roomid` property to both the user and everypost but while feteching all the post that belongs th a specific roomid
showing this error

```
const getRoomID = async () => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'users');
    if (user) {
      const q = query(collectionRef, where('user', '==', user.uid));
      const res = await getDocs(q);
      let data;
      res.forEach((r) => {
        data = r.data();
      });
      return data.roomid;
    }
  };

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'posts');
    if (user) {
      const roomid = await getRoomID();
      const q = query(
        collectionRef,
        orderBy('timestamp', 'desc'),
        where('roomid', '==', roomid)
      );
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        setAllPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
      });
      return unsubscribe;
    }
  };
```

`getROOMID` function get the `roomid` of current logged in user and while using it with snapshot firebase showing this error

`@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.13.0): Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: {"code":"failed-precondition","name":"FirebaseError"}`

How i can build this application I am using NextJS + Firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in version 9.14.0, released 10 November 2022. You should update your Firebase. See [the bug report on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6613).